# InnoSetup - Setting icon of the unisXXX.exe file

Tags: windows, icons, inno-setup

I'm trying to get the icon of the `unisXXX.exe` file to change, and have only been successful by accident.

Here is my .iss (irrelevant fields excluded; have to hand jam this) file:

```
#define AppName "My App"
#define AppExeName "run.exe"
#define AppSource "C:\Path\To\App\Src"

[Setup]
SetupIconFile={#AppSource}\foobar\app.ico
UninstallDisplayName={#AppName}
UninstallDisplayIcon={#AppSource}\foobar\app.ico
;UninstallIconFile={#AppSource}\foobar\app.ico
;Ignored since 5.0.0 apparently

[Files]
Source: "{#AppSource}\{#AppExeName}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{#AppSource}\dll\*"; DestDir: "{app}\dll"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "{#AppSource}\foobar\*"; DestDir: "{app}\foobar"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#AppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#AppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{#AppSource}\foobar\app.ico"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#AppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#AppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{#AppSource}\foobar\app.ico"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#AppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: "{#AppSource}\foobar\app.ico"
```

Now I also have a `[Code]` section that executes a series as follows:

```
CurStepChanged -> CurStep = ssInstall -> IsUpdate -> True -> UninstallPriorVersion
```

Where `IsUpdate` checks the registry values for the installation and if the new installer is newer, then `UninstallPriorVersion` uninstalls the old version before installing the new version.

After I compile the .iss the `app.ico` is applied to the setup executable; and once I run the executable, the icons for the program menu, add/remove programs and desktop icon are all applied correctly. The `unisXXX.exe` however remains as the computer with a disc icon, and it is only changed to the same icon as the setup executable once a new installer version is run and then the old one is uninstalled, giving me a `unis001.exe` with the appropriate icon.

Is there any indication why the icon is not being applied to the `unis000.exe`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No, from the base installer (version 0.0.1) they all have `SetupIconFile`. When installed, the icon is applied to all desired locations, except the `unis000.exe`. Now lets suppose a user downloaded a newer installer (version 0.0.2), when they run the installer, it uninstalls the older application; when it does so, I get `unis001.exe` and the correct icon. So from base install, no icon on the uninstaller, but after replacing the existing install, it suddenly appears.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm not sure how else I would give you an example, the above .iss (excluding fake file paths) is how my script is written. Perhaps you can answer me this, isn't the `SetupIconFile` supposed to use the same icon for the installer and uninstaller?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Turns out this was an artifact of the `IconCache.db`; cleared, reboot and icon is visible.

Comment: @madeslurpy that seems worth adding as an answer.